# How do I get the HTTP POST body in MarkLogic XQuery?

Tags: xquery, marklogic

I'm trying to use the exist-db `request:get-data()` method to get the post data of a request. However, I'm getting the error:

> XDMP-UNDFUN: (err:XPST0017) Undefined function request:get-data()

I did declare the namespace in my header. I don't understand why I still can't use `request:get-data()` or any of the other request: functions

```
declare namespace request="http://exist-db.org/xquery/request";
declare option exist:serialize "method=xml media-type=text/xml indent=yes";

let $post-data := request:get-data()
return $post-data
```

Comment: You tagged marklogic and exist-db. Which are you using to run this code?

Comment: I'm using Marklogic. Is there an equivalent function in Marklogic that lets me get the post data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're looking for [xdmp:get-request-body](http://docs.marklogic.com/xdmp:get-request-body).

Comment: Thanks a lot. Just what I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Sam pointed you to the function you need, but I wanted to respond to another part of your question:

> I did declare the namespace in my header. I don't understand why I still can't use request:get-data() or any of the other request: functions

Each XQuery processing engine [implements standard functions](http://www.w3.org/TR/xquery-30/), but there is other functionality needed that is not defined by the standard. For MarkLogic, you'll use standard functions with the `fn:` prefix.

Each XQuery engine then defines additional functions that will be needed. For Exist DB, some of those are in the "http://exist-db.org/xquery/request" namespace, while MarkLogic uses "http://marklogic.com/xdmp" for a lot of its extension functions.

When you're looking for the MarkLogic equivalent of an Exist DB-specific function, search on http://docs.marklogic.com -- start with the function name, and if that doesn't work, search for the terms that describe what you're trying to do.